# Integer Counter not adding Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int, nsuserdefaults

What I am trying to do is count the number of times a user opens a specific view controller.

- The initial value of the int the first time the user opens the view is 0.
- Then I want to add +1 to the “count” and then save that number in the User Defaults.
- The next time they open the same view controller, User Defaults is recalled to update the current number to the cumulative number of times they have been to this view controller.
- After the user opens the view controller 5 times, I will then display an advertisment.

However, the declaration of the “int” is not allowing me continuously add to the count. I have to start at 0 and the count never goes above 1. Here is my code that I have been trying.

This is my declaration of the "int"

```
    var userOpenVC: Int = 0
```

Here is my code saying that if the "count" doesn't equal 5 then add 1 and save in User Defaults.

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count")

    if (userOpenVC != 5)
    {
        userOpenCategory += 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(userOpenCategory, forKey: "count")
    }

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print(userOpenCategory)

    //THIS WORKS
    if (userOpenCategory == 5)
    {
        adShow.open()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're never actually using the value you've saved in UserDefaults.  This would fix it:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
userOpenVC = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "count")
if userOpenVC != 5 { ...
```

Comment: I suspect your intent is to increment the value each time the view controller shows vs. loads, so you may want to move the functionality suggested to the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such a simple fix that I don't know how I didn't realize it. I appreciate it.